# Node.js install from local files

Tags: node.js, npm

I made a modification to an `npm` package locally on my machine, and now I want to globally install the modified version, dependencies and all. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `npm install` you can install a module specified by a directory instead of a name in the `npm` registry, see:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

> ```
> npm install (with no args, in package dir)
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
> npm install <tarball file>
> npm install <tarball url>
> npm install <folder>
> ```

See the last 3 options - you can use a tarball file that you have prepared yourself, a tarball URL that you have hosted somewhere (like on GitHub), or a directory (folder) containing the module with `package.json` file.

If you are in the directory with your modified version, then you can install it globally with:

```
npm install -g .
```

Also, you can use `npm link` to create a globally-installed symbolic link from to the current folder, see:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

This option can be convenient during development.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried doing this, and it wasn't working. Turns out I had not specified a `bin` in the `package.json` file